# Monodroid Intent Service's BroadcastReceiver not firing OnReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, xamarin.android, intentservice

I've been attempting to get a toy intent service running for monodroid [essentially going off of this source material](http://android10.org/index.php/articleswhitepapers/314-android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics) and I've been having some issues and I've gotten it down to the broadcast receiver. More than anything I'm suspicious of the `ACTION_RESP` string. If nothing else I could certainly stand maybe confirmation of that and maybe the correct way to set an action that the receiver can see.
So, this is what I have thus far...

### My Intent Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Util;

namespace Mono_For_Android_Intent_Service
{
    [Service]
    public class TestIntentService : IntentService
    {
        public static String PARAM_IN_MSG = "imsg";
        public static String PARAM_OUT_MSG = "omsg";

        #region Constructor
        public TestIntentService()
            : base("TestIntentService")
        {
        }
        #endregion

        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            string msg = intent.GetStringExtra(PARAM_IN_MSG);
            //Do Stuff
            string result = msg + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Intent BroadcastIntent = new Intent(this,typeof(Mono_For_Android_Intent_Service.MainActivity.MyBroadcastReceiver));
            BroadcastIntent.SetAction(Mono_For_Android_Intent_Service.MainActivity.MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
            BroadcastIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
            BroadcastIntent.PutExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG,result);
            SendBroadcast(BroadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

### Main Activity and Broadcast Receiver

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Mono_For_Android_Intent_Service
{
    [Activity(Label = "Mono_For_Android_Intent_Service", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public partial class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private MyBroadcastReceiver Receiver;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
            filter.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
            Receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
            RegisterReceiver(Receiver, filter);

            var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.start);
            button.Click += (s,e)=>
            {
                Intent msgIntent= new Intent(this,typeof(TestIntentService));
                msgIntent.PutExtra(TestIntentService.PARAM_IN_MSG,"Me message, arh");
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Starting intent service!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                StartService(msgIntent);

            };

            TextView txtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.status);
        }

        public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public static readonly string ACTION_RESP = "Mono_For_Android_Intent_Service.Intent.Action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Firing On Receive!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                var activity = (MainActivity)context;
                TextView txtView = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.status);
                txtView.Text = intent.GetStringExtra(TestIntentService.PARAM_OUT_MSG).ToString();
                Toast.MakeText(context, "On Receive complete!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Am I doing it wrong? Am I close? I'd like to think I'm pretty close but, by all means if I'm in timbucktoo I would like to know...
2. If so what correct way to go about sending and receiving that broadcast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your broadcast receiver to be registered with the system, you need to add the [BroadcastReceiver] attribute.

Sample:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/App/OneShotAlarm.cs